# Gradle issues when importing an android studio project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently having some issues when attempting to import an android studio project.

Initially, when importing the project, I am met with:

```
Unable to get Gradle wrapper properties from: C:\Users\user\Downloads\topic 6.3\topic6\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
```

I hit "OK" to create files and project loads. I then try to build the project, however I am met with:

```
ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

The original gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mad.topic6"
        minSdkVersion 19
        // so we don't need runtime permissions
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/
    // latest release
    //implementation 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    // latest release candidate (RC)
    implementation 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.1.0-rc1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1'
}
```

I am able to fix the first issue by adding this at the top of the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google() // For Gradle 4.0+
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // For Gradle < 4.0
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

}
```

}

This solves the issue, but i am then met with:

```
    Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.jar
  - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom
  - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.jar
```

And I am unable to find a way to resolve this issue.

Comment: your kotlin plugin is installed ? looks like it isn't well in the current location of gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Change your project level gradle file to this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused. There only appears to be one gradle file in the project. Do i need to have 2 different files?

Comment: Your project structure is wrong then. There must be atleast 2 gradle files. One for the application level dependencies and another for module level. I suggest you to ditch this project completely and create a new Project in Android studio.